# How to merge two data streams in Alteryx

Tags: append, alteryx

Alteryx

Table 1 is a google sheet file. It has x fields with primary key.
Every day to that table is added the weekday with the x data
For example:
Monday
Tuesday (is added on Tuesday) and so on.
My problem is that my workflow has a formula that does calculations with all the Weekdays.

Example:
Balance = All_Income - Monday - Tuesday - Wednesday - Thursday - Friday - Saturday - Sunday

But today for example, in the google sheet data I don't have the other weekdays except Monday and Tuesday, so I get the error "Unknown Variable" for Thursday.

I've inserted a Text Input and added all the weekdays.
I want to (Append maybe) these two data streams together so that I have all the weekdays there.
So if I run the calculations I have all the weekdays there.
Right now that formula works only on Sunday, when all weekdays are inserted as columns.
Any idea how to achieve this?
(p.s Creating the weekdays as columns in the google sheet with empty rows is not an option).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by creating a Text Input with the same column names (headers) as the other Data Source and performing a union.

Apparently I needed to perform a IF statement to check all Weekdays if they exist and replace the null values with.

If anyone encounters the same error, feel free to contact for help :)

Comment: This solution only works if you know the names of the fields and you input them into the Text Input tool. That is manual effort that can be avoided using my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Transpose tool to verticalise the days of the week. Then Summarize using the primary key and sum the [value] field. That will give you the balance regardless of which days of the week are present in your worksheet. This technique applies to any problem in which one needs to aggregate multiple fields which may or may not be present or known.

Here is the simplest path to victory:
1. Input worksheet.
2. Connect Transpose tool.
3. In Transpose Key Columns, select only primary key.
4. In Transpose Data Columns, deselect all fields except for days of week and Dynamic or Unknown Columns. This will still work even if the worksheet doesn't have all the days of the week because as they come in, the Dynamic or Unknown Columns option will select them as Data columns.
5. In Transpose Missing Columns, select Ignore.
6. Connect Summarize tool. 
7. In Summarize, group by primary key and sum on [Value] field.

From here, you can rename the sum_value field to Balance or something else friendly. You can also use a Join tool, joining on primary keys, to the original worksheet to get back to where you started with the new aggregated value.